# Is there a random function in python that gets a fair result in a certain range?

Tags: python

I am just wanting to get a certain integer from 0 ~ 99 **fairly** using Python.
Currently, my code is:

```py
import random
var = random.randint(0, 99)
```

but seemingly, it just always returned an integer from 0 ~ 49.
Can anyone tell me why? Any modifications or suggestions targeting the code is appreciated.
Thank you!

Comment: How many test runs did you do…?

Comment: @deceze, I did a lot. Like 10.

Comment: what do you mean by `always returned an integer from 0 ~ 49`

Comment: the method you are using should be fair, once I used matplotlib to plot a random scatter in a large sample by `randint` function, the separation is fair.

Comment: 10 is, like, *not* a lot… https://www.dilbert.com/strip/2001-10-25

Comment: Test it with something like `counts = Counter(random.randint(0, 99) for _ in range(10000))` and see what counts looks like.

Comment: To be clear, it’s entirely possible with a *random number generator* to randomly get, say, ten 9s in a row. That doesn’t make the generator “unfair”, it’s just random. To prove a RNG is biased or “unfair” in some way, you need a much much *much* larger sample size.

Comment: OK. Thank you...

Comment: I used this variable as a part in my game. Thank you.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Instead use
random.randrange(start(opt),stop,step(opt))

Import random

var=random.randrange(0,99)

Comment: If you use randrange, the second argument needs to be 100.